# Java Files.Walk to filter files only with starting with "O_"

Tags: java, file

Could you please help me how it is possible to filter only the files which is starting with "O_"? For me StartsWith and EndsWith methods didn't work.The result was always an empty list.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(SOURCEDIR)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(filePath -> {
        if (true){
            System.out.println(filePath.getFileName());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `filter(p -> p.getFileName().startsWith("O_"))` did not work?

Answer (score 13):

Really old question, but I still find it when I search for some directories reading ways.

Anyway, assylias commented the first post to add :

```
filter(p -> p.getFileName().startsWith("O_"))
```

Which is not working because there is missing the .toString() function. With this you can solve the problem by a more efficient way like it :

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(SOURCEDIR))
    .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().startsWith("O_"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which one uses the Java 8 Syntax and provides you a standalone line which does the work.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the work:

```java
    Files.walk(Paths.get(SOURCEDIR))
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(filePath -> {
        String name = filePath.getFilename().toString();
        if (name.startWith("_O")) {
            System.out.println(filePath.getFileName());
        }
    });
```